# i have custom list view using adapter , in list view have two buttons one for make a phonecall secon one send SMS

Tags: android

[image: my requirement Image]

When I click call button then make a phone call and contact number getting from JSON how add number to the button?

Comment: Read more about gridview with custom Array Adapter and how to use Json data with android application.

Comment: tq for replay @ HourGlass .. im new for android please help me

Comment: For this you need to create a adapter and pass the json data to the adapter. In the getview of the adapter you need to inflate the view with the onclick listener of the button with call option. Post whatever things you have done. Based on that we'll proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

In your ListView adapter, bind the phone number to the call button using setTag and on the click of the call button get the phone number using getTag.

Answer (score 0):

Provide any code. that you write so far. Don't ask for code next time. see [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34507597/edit#)

See for [json example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm) and [customized listview](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html) and 
adapter's code would be like this

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
ArrayList<String> phonenumbers = new ArrayList<>();
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<String> time = new ArrayList<>();

public ListAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> numbers) {
    context = c;
    phonenumbers = numbers;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return phonenumbers.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    Button button = null;
    TextView txtTime = null;
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttoncall);
        holder.buttonCall = button;
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    holder.buttonCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Make you call here on this number
            String numberToCall = phonenumbers.get(position);
            //numberToCall is the clicked button's number
            //you can make call now.

        }
    });

    return v;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public Button buttonCall;

}
}
```